# comparing a character with a string

Tags: java

I have a basic question when comparing a character with a string, i am using the following code.In my code `string` has 5 letters when the `inputChar` doesn't matches the string  `count` returns 5.but I want the `count` to be 1, since I gave 1 character. How can I do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                if(inputchar!=string.charAt(i)){
                    count ++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just change the condition in your if block..... change it from '!=' to '=='....

Comment: Why do you have a `count` variable at all if you don't want to count?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think OP wants to check if any of the characters matches the input or not, in this way having a count make sense

Comment: please make your question clear.Do you want to check the number of characters not matching inputchar in the string?if not then why are you looping over it?

Answer (score 1):

return count inside your condition if you want to return on first occurrence:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
     if(inputchar!=string.charAt(i)){
         count ++;
         return count;
     }
}
```

but if you want to return `0` if any of the character matches this should do the work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
     if(inputchar!=string.charAt(i)){
         count ++;
     }
}

if(count == string.length()) //this means non of the characters at string matches inputchar 
    return 1;
return 0; //this means at least one the characters in string matches inputchar
```